# Upload file to Google Drive using access token, What scope of authentication is required?

Tags: php, curl, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file to Google Drive with PHP.

For the authorization code, I am using the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive  
https://docs.google.com/feeds/  
https://docs.googleusercontent.com/  
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/
```

I already received a valid `refresh_token`, and I'm able to use it to fetch a new `access_token` anytime I wish.

Now the problem is when I am trying to perform the upload using this `access_token` (**it is not exprired, and not used yet**) it says:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => stdClass Object
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [domain] => global
                            [reason] => required
                            [message] => Login Required
                            [locationType] => header
                            [location] => Authorization
                        )

                )

            [code] => 401
            [message] => Login Required
        )
)
```

I am using curl with following header:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Content-Type: text/plain
    [1] => Content-Length: 503242
    [2] => Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHES6ZRWXZkZDDi6AFV9PK2QonHp93nIfJbYqipXFT1uCsg
    [3] => GData-Version: 3.0
)
```

And following URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media
```

The CURL Command is like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($file));
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Any Help will be heartly appreciated...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

The only OAuth scope you need to upload a file to Drive is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`.

For all possible scopes, check the documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes

By the way, the Drive API is not GData-based so you don't need to add the `GData-Version` header to your requests.

I'd also recommend you to compare your requests with those sent by the OAuth 2.0 Playground so that it should be easy to spot the error:

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following scope:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

Also verify that you have gone through the steps given in documentation thoroughly

https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth

If you don't want to use curl.You can use insert method of Googlephpclientlibarary of inserting files.

Otherwise compare request with OauthPlayground as mentioned by Claudio

Comment: I was in very much hurry, and after much effort the whole night, I came to a point where I made a minor modification in the Google API Client Library... And guess what! It works!!

I am off desk right now, Will post the changes later...

Thanks, **Claudio** and **Trim Kaur**

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , not CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS